# Daily localNotification what date should you set?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I could see that if i set the notification to be daily , the fire date to set most be a future one , so that if i set a daily notification with a past date- it will not appear tomorrow .

My question is, if today is `1.1.16` , and i set notification date to `4.1.16` , and then set the daily notification with :

```
 UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                        notification.fireDate = newdate;
                        notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
```

Will i see the notification also tomorrow ? or everyday starting from `4.1.16` ?

Comment: It will fire every day if you set the repeat interval to kCFCalendarUnitDay.

Comment: Please visit - http://useyourloaf.com/blog/repeating-an-ios-local-notification.html